# OBIEE 11g: Pass string contained special character through dashboard prompt

Tags: dashboard, obiee

Is there anyway to pass a string that contained special character (ex: ') into a presentation variable through dashboard prompt?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a prompt for presentation variable.
 In Create prompt screen , create a variable prompt and select 'prompt for presentation variable'. It will accept special characters as well for setting presentation variable value.

[Create variable prompt screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tllCR.png)

[dashboard screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7Yeu.png)

Another way is to use GO url, where you can pass the value as a parameter in the url and is used to set a prompt. In prompt you can set a presentation variable using this parameter value.
Refer below doc to learn more.
https: //docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/bi.1111/e16364/apiwebintegrate.htm#BIEIT364

Comment: Hi,

I have try to create a column prompt and assign it with presentation variable called AGENTNAME.

In the report, I have put the following formula as report filter:

tblstructure.agentname='@{AGENTNAME}'

After apply the filter, the report shows me no results and the following shows on the report:

tblstructure.agentname = 'MLIFA''''IAA BIMGI MFHGAFA'

Comment: What was your excepted value of agentname. It seems some value is coming as agent name. In filter did you selected 'presentation variable' option and given simply the presentation variable name without quotes?

Comment: Hi, The expected value as per image above, but the expected value of agent name could be different. For example a'bcd or ab'cd or abc'd or abcd'. Yes, already selected presentation variable as my option and put AGNETNAME(as per image above) as presentation variable name.